# A simple Sitemap editor?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I just wonder if there's an easy application that would allow me and others to edit a sitemap for ASP.NET in a more visual way. For me, the XML format isn't difficult to understand but I want someone else to modify a current sitemap for me and this person is unfamiliar with XML and would not understand a non-graphical interface.

So, is there a simple tool that allows me to edit a sitemap visually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [ASP.NET 2.0 Web Menu Editor](http://blogs.ipona.com/davids/archive/2006/07/08/5516.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these:

http://astuteo.com/slickmap/

http://www.lovelycharts.com/

http://www.slickplan.com/